# Should this question receive a [pascal] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

[Function to find text between two tags](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82368/function-to-find-text-between-two-tags)

The question is purely procedural. Also, OP explicitly demands "default uses" clauses. Furthermore, even the compiler directives (see [1](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=$I) and [2](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/3.0.0/prog/progsu38.html)) related to the `$IOCHECK` are portable, as a result, one should be able to compile this code with the major pascal compilers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *one should be able to compile this code with the major pascal compilers.*

Being able to compile this code with major pascal compilers is one thing, writing the code *as being meant to be compiled* in the major pascal compilers is another thing.

Let's say that you wrote some C code, and it just happened to be C++ compilable as well, would the question then have both tags? In my opinion, no.

By specifying only one language tag, other reviewers know better what things may or may not be possible in that language.

In my opinion, the question does not need a [pascal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pascal) tag.

Related: Some sites have [an entire tag](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglot) for code that runs in multiple languages, Code Review questions should specify the language the code was written in, not all the languages it just happens to compile in.

Comment: But what about the first thing I mentioned? Code is purely procedural.

Comment: In another way, pascal code should be tagged as delphi just because the compiler used?

Comment: @cpicanco Doesn't matter that the code is purely procedural. It is possible to write procedural code in Delphi. It is Delphi code, as it was written in Delphi.

Comment: I am following the description of the Pascal tag. So, it is matter.

Comment: @cpicanco Then it sounds to me like you should consider following the Delphi tag as well.

Comment: I am doing so, Delphi as a dialect, is only evidently recognize when 1) you use specific VCL or non visual components or 2) you use "third party" specific components or 3) you inherit and use the object oriented goodies or 4) you use specific compiler directives or 5) something I am missing (sorry about it). This statement is returning false to me :)

Comment: @cpicanco By using the delphi tag on the question though you are essentially saying that you can use all those things. If the question would be tagged with pascal then it would signal that the possible improvements are limited to the things that are possible in Pascal. Again, I think tagging this question with pascal is a bad idea.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure why this specific question should be Delphi instead Pascal.

Comment: @cpicanco The delphi compiler was used to compile it, therefore it should be tagged with delphi.

Comment: Please, could you add this info in the answer?